# Erroneous FS0064 warning? This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations

Tags: f#

I am trying to make a class which implements a generic .NET IComparer interface for use with the various System.Collections.Generic collections. This IComparer will map the collection's values into an ordering key using an externally provided function.

An example application might be a `SortedSet<City>` which sorts by population, but where the population is dynamically retrieved from an external data source which is separately maintained and updated.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

type ExternalComparer<'T>(compareBy: ('T -> 'U) when 'U :> IComparable) =
    let compareBy = compareBy

    interface IComparer<'T> with
        member this.Compare(a, b) =
            let x = compareBy a
            let y = compareBy b
            if x < y then -1 else if x > y then 1 else 0
```

The compiler issues the following warning on the `if x < y` expression, specifically on the `x`:

```
Warning FS0064  This construct causes code to be less generic than 
indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'U has been 
constrained to be type 'IComparable'.
```

In fact, I intend the type variable 'U to be constrained to be the type 'IComparable,' and I tried to express that intent with the `when 'U :> IComparable` constraint in the definition of the `compareBy` function type.

Is this warning message erroneous, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution - just accept a function of type `'T -> IComparable` is the right thing to do, even if it means that the users of your `ExternalComparer` might need to insert an upcast to make the code compile.

To explain why you were getting the error, your class has only one generic type parameter `'T` and the `'U` parameter is missing there - so the compiler constrained it to `IComparable`. If you wanted to fix that, you'd have to add another generic parameter:

```
type ExternalComparer<'T, 'U when 'U :> IComparable>(compareBy: ('T -> 'U)) =
    let compareBy = compareBy

    interface IComparer<'T> with
        member this.Compare(a, b) =
            let x = compareBy a :> IComparable
            let y = compareBy b :> IComparable
            if x < y then -1 else if x > y then 1 else 0
```

Additionally, I also had to add `:> IComparable` so that we convert the results from whatever `'U` is to `IComparable` that can be compared. This adds another generic parameter, which is quite silly.

If you wanted to avoid that, you could use a static member that converts a `'T -> 'U` function to
`'T -> IComparable` function before passing it to the constructor:

```
type ExternalComparer<'T>(compareBy: ('T -> IComparable)) =
    let compareBy = compareBy
    interface IComparer<'T> with
        member this.Compare(a, b) =
            let x = compareBy a
            let y = compareBy b
            if x < y then -1 else if x > y then 1 else 0
    static member Create(compareBy : 'T -> #IComparable) =
      ExternalComparer(fun v -> compareBy v :> IComparable)
```

Now you can use the `Create` method nicely:

```
ExternalComparer<string>(fun v -> int v :> _) // Requires upcast
ExternalComparer<string>.Create(fun v -> int v) // Works directly!
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're defining the `compareBy` type to return a `'U`, constrained to `IComparable`, when you could more clearly have defined it to return an `IComparable` directly, like this:

```
type ExternalComparer<'T>(compareBy: ('T -> IComparable)) =
```

Since you know `'U` will always be an `IComparable`, the use of a generic type is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you could collapse a chunk of the code into an object expression:

```
let bigCity = {Name="NYC"; population = 1_000_000}
let smallCity = {Name="KC"; population = 1000}

let cityComparer compFunc = { new System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<'T> with 
                                override __.Compare(c1, c2) = 
                                    let x = compFunc c1
                                    let y = compFunc c2
                                    if x < y then -1 else if x > y then 1 else 0
}

let comp = cityComparer (fun x -> x.population)
comp.Compare(smallCity,bigCity)
//val it : int = -1
```